# При добавлении sitemap.xml, яндекс выдает: "Ошибка HTTP"

Tags: sitemap

Вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>http://site.ru/</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Кодировка: `UTF-8`

Ошибок в sitemap.xml нет, но яндекс выдает: `Ошибка HTTP`. Это означает что статус http не равен 200. Проверил, у меня статус `304 (Not Modified)`. Но как исправить?

Comment: 304 означает что данные берутся из кеша. Удалите кеш в браузере и увидите 200 статус.

Answer (score 2):

В вопросе на текущий момент не указано полной информации для того, чтобы дать ответ.

Дело в том, что веб-серверы (nginx, httpd, iis) в конфигурации по умолчанию не кэшируют статические файлы, такие как gif, jpeg, txt, css, xml и многие другие.

Какой у вас веб-сервер -- непонятно. Как именно вы его настроили кэшировать статику -- тоже непонятно. Если так -- то нужны конфиги, чтобы понять, где не так сделано.

Могут быть даже весьма экзотические случаи, когда sitemap.xml может оказаться не xml-файлом, а скриптом, который генерирует подобный файл на лету из базы данных и тогда нужно разбираться не с настройками веб-сервера, а смотреть код скрипта, какие заголовки и по каким условиям вы выполняете.

Comment: у меня обычный хостинг. На других сайтах работает (200). Даже если все удалить и оставить sitemap.xml, то все равно 304

Comment: @Ilnyr обычный хостинг - это как обычный порошок в рекламе. Все про него говорят, но никто не видел. Дайте тогда ссылку на свой сайт, там разберёмся

Comment: Вот ссылка на sitemap: http://iske-elmet.ru/sitemap.xml

Comment: Судя по ответам веб-сервера у вас установлен nginx + varnish. Скажите -- это ваш собственный "обычный" хостинг (т.е. вы можете показать конфиг-файлы nginx и varnish) или это коммерческий хостинг и вы не можете предоставить конфиги? Судя по строке v07.hostline.ru подозреваю, что скорее верно второе (вы не сотрудник, а их клиент) -- тогда вам логичнее обратиться в техподдержку провайдера. С xml-файлом на первый взгляд всё хорошо: при первом обращении отдаётся 200 OK, при последующих 304 Not Modified.

Comment: Плюс, на всякий-всякий пожарный случай уточним, что sitemap.xml -- это не скрипт, а статический файл. Так?

Comment: Да, я клиент хостинга, поэтому конфиги не могу предоставить.
В моем случае sitemap.xml статический файл

Answer (score 1):

У Вас на сервере настроено кэширование статических файлов, скорее всего, в том числе и `xml` файлов. Чтобы исправить ситуацию, надо знать, какой веб-сервер и на какой системе Вы используете.
Если Nginx, то смотрите файлы `nginx.conf` , `/etc/nginx/sites-available`, для нужного сайта ищете правила для статических файлов, примерно такого вида: `location ~* ^.+.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz|xml)$ {` , подробнее можно почитать про [настройку кэширования nginx здесь](http://vpsvds.ru/statyi/nastroyka-hostingov/optimizaciya-hostinga-rucenter)
. Удаляете расширения файлов которые кэшировать не надо, и перезагружаете настройки nginx: #`nginx -s reload`
Если используете `Apache`, то смотрим `.htaccess` в корне сайта, файлы конфигов из `conf-avialiable` и `conf.d` . Ищем что-то типа:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<FilesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|js|xml)$">
        ExpiresDefault A604800
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Удаляем `xml` из списка расширений и рестартуем Апач.
Если используете какую-то панель управления сервером, то смотрим настройки там.